# Form with multiple images does not submit on mobile devices

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have form in which I have 8 fields for image uploading. On mobile browsers, a button allows users to take a photo and attach it.  When any user uses this feature while submitting the form, it does not submit.  It waits for some time and reverts back to the form.  While debugging, I found that form is not considered as submitted.  It seems to be like a timeout or something.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="addClaim" class="form-horizontal" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][1]" placeholder="Fault Image" />

<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][2]" placeholder="Fault Image" />

<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][3]" placeholder="Fault Image" />


<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][4]" placeholder="Fault Image" />


<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][5]" placeholder="Fault Image" />


<input type="file" class="form-control" name="group-a[fault_img][6]" placeholder="Fault Image" />

</form>


in CI Controller under my form submit handler. 
<?php 

$postData = $this->input->post();
if(isset($postData) && !empty($postData) ){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($postData);
  die;
}
```

This works well on desktop and mobile when I select images from my image gallery, but when I use a different option on mobile, which says take photo or video, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is it only not working on mobile?

Comment: Can you please show us code what did you tryed?

Comment: @davidev yes its not working on mobile only.